# Making JOptionPane not case sensitive?

Tags: java, swing, case-insensitive, joptionpane

I can't seem to find out anywhere but if I remember correctly there was something you could add to the end of a `JOptionPane` statement to make it case insensitive ? Here's my code, focusing on string a

```
....  scanner.close();
for (int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i += 2)
{
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit misleading as this has absolutely nothing to do with JOptionPane. The JOptionPane is just a tool to get user input. The case sensitivity part is simply in your if block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really about JOptionPane, but what happens after it has done its work :-)

Use [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) when comparing the two strings.

```
if (a.equalsIgnoreCase(answer) && input.equals("instant")) {
            ^^^^^^^^^^
    ...
}
else if (a.equalsIgnoreCase(answer) && input.equals("generate")) {
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
    ...
}
```